# Find window previously opened by window.open

Tags: javascript, window.open

We've got the following situation, running from a single domain:

Page A uses `window.open()` to open a named window (a popup player). `window.open()` gives page A a reference to the window.

User now reloads page A. The reference to the named window is lost. Using `window.open()` to "find" the window has the unfortunate side effect of reloading it (undesirable). Is there any other way to get a reference to this window?

Comment: wow there's another question almost exactly like this opened just this morning.

Comment: Can you post it here? I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this:

```
var playerUrl = 'http://my.player...';
var popupPlayer= window.open('', 'popupPlayer', 'width=150,height=100') ;
if(popupPlayer.location.href == 'about:blank' ){
    popupPlayer.location = playerUrl ;
}
popupPlayer.focus();
```

It will open a blank window with a unique name. Since the url is blank, the content of the window will not be reloaded.

Comment: This looks great. Will try when I get a chance.

Comment: Instead of popupPlayer.location I recommend using popupPlayer.location.href.
This avoids problems when using === instead of == (e.g. CoffeeScript does this automatically).

Comment: There can be issues if the URL of the popup window is not within the same domain as the current window. Wrap the IF in a try/catch to avoid issues.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, no there isn't..

A kind-of-dirty-but-i-guess-it-will-work hack would be to periodically reset the reference on the parent window from within the popup using window.opener, with something like this code:

```
    setInterval(function() {
        if(window.opener) {
            window.opener.document.myPopupWindow = window
        }
    }, 100)
```

In the parent window, you'll be able to access document.myPopupWindow, even after a reload (well, 100ms after the reload). This should work cross browser.

Comment: It is, I've checked. 

When the opening window is closed though, you'd have 10 nullpointers per second with the code above. Have modified it to check for null :)

Comment: Can't you stop the interval once the window is found?!

Comment: Josh: no, that way it wouldn't work after more than one reload of the parent window.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you did is destroy the parent (page A) of the created window (Popup), so it has no more reference to the original parent therefore you can't get a direct reference.

The only solution I can think of is using a browser that offers you added javascript capability to cycle through active windows (tabs) and find one that has a special property (ie: your reloaded page A) that gets recognized by the popup.

Unfortunately I guess only firefox has some added capability or extension that gives you this flexibility. (it is also a security risk though)

Comment: No dice. Needs to be x-browser.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Add this code in the popup:

```
function updateOpener() {
    if (window.opener)
        window.opener.document.myPopupWindow = window;
    else
        setTimeout(updateOpener, 100);
}

updateOpener();
```

And this in onload of the parent window. To make sure myPopupWindow have been set wait 100 ms before accessing it.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    if (document.myPopupWindow) 
        document.myPopupWindow.focus();
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the windows share a common Url origin you can register a ServiceWorker and then access all windows from the ServiceWorker: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients

AFAIK You won't be able to pass a reference to other windows from WorkerService to your window but you can establish communications with the ServiceWorker via

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/postMessage

Answer (score 0):

It Might help someone, If you opened an child tab and after refreshing the parent tab, you still want to focus on that child tab instead of opening new child tab: -

```
const chatPopup = window.open('', 'chatPopup');
if (chatPopup.location.href === 'about:blank' || !chatPopup.location.href.includes('/chat')) {
  this.openNewWindow = window.open('/chat', 'chatPopup');}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).