# Access a window by window name

Tags: javascript

If I open a window using

```
window.open('myurl.html', 'windowname', 'width=100,height=100');
```

How do I refer to the new window (from the same page that opened it) using 'windowname'?  This question is specifically about this.  I'm aware that I could save a reference to the handle by using "var mywin = window.open(...)" but I don't care about that in this situation.

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Assign the return value of `window.open()` to a variable. This is the only proper solution.

Comment: -1 for not reading Daves question. `var mywin=window.open()` is exactly, what Dave doesn't care about.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question... You are saying you want a way to reference a window that you open from the opener, but then saying you don't care about how to do it?

Comment: Look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455158/find-window-previously-opened-by-window-open

Comment: @Dave: The accepted answer is simply incorrect, see [Petr's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18542652/157247).

Answer (score -7, accepted):

afaik there's no way like `windows['windowname']`.
The 'windowname' assigned in window.open() can be addressed as a target in `<a target="windowname" [...] >`

Comment: This shouldn't be the answer. See Jack Allan's link in the question's comments.

Answer (score 23):

In firefox (might work in other browsers too, but now it's not my concern) I was able to reference one window accross multiple page loads with

```
var w = window.open("", "nameofwindow");
```

This opens new window if it doesn't exist and return reference to existing window if it does exist without changing contents of the window.

With jQuery I was then able to append new content, to make quick collection of interresting links like this

```
$('body', w.document).append(link_tag);
```

Comment: what is `nameofwindow`

Comment: @Dwigh it's up to you to define it

Answer (score 22):

If you didn't save a reference to the window then there is no way to restore it. However, **if** that window is still open and **if** the page loaded there belongs to the same domain as your page, you can run JavaScript code in it:

```
window.open("javascript:doSomething()", "windowname");
```

Whether that's sufficient in your scenario depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Ugh. Even if that works.. i hope nobody really uses it. But I wonder if something like `window.open("javascript:void(window.opener.windowname = window);", "windowname")` would work... that would do exactly what the guy asked for (not than anyone should actually use such a hack)

Comment: @ThiefMaster, I thought this was a rather elegant solution (assuming that it actually works). What is your objection to it, exactly?

Comment: It's a hack for a self-made problem - at least I can't imagine a reason why it would be impossible to store the window reference. You can always do something like `wins['foo'] = window.open('...', 'foo');` giving you access to a name-to-window-object mapping througt the global `var `wins`

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Usually the problem is that the opening window navigates to a different page so keeping the reference is impossible. Still, I agree - this isn't a great solution.

Answer (score 8):

Petr is correct:

```
var w = window.open("", "nameofwindow");
```

works in all browsers, I am using it to retrieve the reference to the window object previously opened by a different page. The only problem is the initial opening of the page, if the popup does not exist, you will get a new window with a blank page.

I tried invoking a Javascript function inside the context of the other document in order to check whether I opened a new window or retrieved the already active page. If the check fails, I just invoke window.open again to actually load my popup content:

```
var w = window.open("http://mydomain.com/myPopup", "nameofwindow");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50513

Comment: Correction to above - it only works if the calling window opened the window you're trying to access, which is part of the question. Sorry about that, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. The windowName is just to be used in `target="..."` of links/forms or to use the same name again in another `window.open` call to open a new url in that window.

Comment: and you gave exact same solution

Answer (score 0):

Try open that window with the name, but URL is '' again, to check if it's a blank window or not. If it's in open, then you will get the window; if not, a new window open, and you need close it.
Add the children in localStorage will help to prevent to open the new blank window.

Please check my code in https://github.com/goldentom66/ParentChildWindow

Answer (score -2):

Sorry I am posting late, but if you still have the other window open, and they are on the same domain, you can run, on the first window:

```
function getReference(w) {
   console.log('Hello from', w);
}
```

And on the second window:

```
window.opener.getReference(window);
```