# Open a window and share it among tabs?

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

I have a page that uses `window.open()` with a window name to pop up another window that will act as a presentation screen for my app:

```
window.open(url, 'my-presentation-win', 'resizable');
```

Now, that works well, and if I trigger that action, and then navigate to a different page, but then come back to the original page and trigger the action again, it brings the original popup window back into focus (the name is honored).

However, if I load the same HTML page in two different browser tabs (Chrome on OSX), and trigger that action in each, I end up with two different windows (each presumably with the name `my-presentation-win`?). Is there a way for that window to be re-used, when its used by the same app running in different tabs?

Comment: _"Is there a way for that window to be re-used, when its used by the same app running in different tabs?"_ Tried using web workers to detect if popup window already open ? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker ; see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645685/how-to-clear-the-contents-of-an-iframe-from-another-iframe/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible :(

[Access a window by window name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7244043/4799064)