# Need to find a particular URL is loaded in browser or not

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html page which contains a link, by clicking on this link I am opening a pop-up window (using **window.open()** ).

Now I have another html file which also has a link pointing to the same URL.

My requirement is that when I click on the link I need to check if there is any pop-up with this URL already opened in the browser instance and if so, focus on that particular pop-up.

Comment: You can just give the window a name related to the URL. So same URLs will have same window names and attempt to open second URL will open it in the first window.

Comment: Thanks you for the Quick reply,
As per your suggestion it will reload the page , but my requirement is to just focus to that window.

Comment: `var w = window.open('yoururl'); w.focus()`?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2455480/961695 @putvande read the question please.

Comment: @ Yuriy Galanter,
Thanks again, looks great i will try this.

Comment: The only solution I see to this is some serverside magic. Something real time like socket IO. Accessing across tabs isn't something you can do without a browser plugin.